# Index of all commas except those in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

How to exclude commas that are in small (less than 20 characters) parentheses?

> Get index of this comma, but (not this , comma). Get other commas like, or ,or, 1,1 2 ,2. (not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma, if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)

Expected output for [this example](https://regex101.com/r/wGJqCJ/1) all indices of commas:
`[23, 71, 76, 79, 82, 87, 132]`

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Specifically, could you provide an input sample with your expected output?

Comment: The syntax you're requesting is not, formally, a regular language -- that's why all the answers use extensions like backreferences that aren't part of "real" regular expression languages. There's a great deal of academic literature about what a true regex can and can't match -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language for a high-level intro -- and when you get into extensions, the classic (very fast) algorithms may no longer work -- meaning matching can involve backtracking and thus get slower or more memory-intensive. See also https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to match and exclude the characters that you don't want in the match result.

In this case, you can match 1-20 between parenthesis where the comma should not be matched.

```
\([^()]{1,20}\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^()]{1,20}` Match 1-20 times any char except `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Exclude the characters from the match result
- `|` Or
- `,` Match a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADfutH/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dZAxT8QwDIX3/IqnTgmKql6ZGWA4dIIBCZjuDin03GsESarESIeA315c9QYWpjif7fdsj588pHg5TT6MKTMyHemkVMEVqqq6JYaPBzoh9eDBF3QpBGfx@sHQMfEC7YJNjbkh8UB5IQXv/o0knzJsyhYru0IL29bqT7fBzfMT9PE/M98jpEzCXETboBtcdh1TLnCCfSz@MGcJo/yjBIWKkfHV6FjKoiyTq53evmiz/1rZtvnZGX3xeLd5kGd9vbk337ZS4u07mjffhrqwy6wbg15GD@KxXKbu5yrR1Gdpi2L2asw@sj4LmGn6BQ)

**Example code**

```
import regex

s = """Get index of this comma, but (not this , comma). Get other commas like , or ,or, 1,1 2 ,2.
(not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma, if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)"""
pattern = r"\([^()]{1,20}\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,"
indices = [m.start(0) for m in regex.finditer(pattern, s)]
print(indices)
```

**Output**

```
[23, 71, 76, 79, 82, 87, 132]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex pattern: `(,)|(\([^()]{0,20}\))`

Intuition behind this pattern:

- `(,)` looks for all commas. These are stored in capturing group 1.
- `(\([^()]{0,20}\))` looks for all parentheses with at most 20 characters in between. These are stored in capturing group 2.

We can then find all matches from group 1 only to exclude those commas within parentheses of length 20.

Now to find the indices for these matches, use [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) combined with [Match.start()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) and [Match.group()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) to find the starting index for each match from group 1:

```
import re

string = """Get index of this comma, but (not this , comma). Get other commas like , or ,or, 1,1 2 ,2.
(not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma, if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)"""

indices = [m.start(1) for m in re.finditer('(,)|(\([^()]{0,20}\))', string) if m.group(1)]

print(indices)
# > [23, 71, 76, 79, 82, 87, 132]
print([string[index] for index in indices])
# > [',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',']
```

`m.start(1)` returns the starting index for group 1 matches. Since `re.finditer()` returns matches from all capturing groups, adding `if m.group(1)` requires that a match is found for group 1 (matches from other groups are `None`).

Edit: This ignores parentheses with 20 or fewer characters inside, which is not consistent with your first statement but is consistent with what the example explains. If you want *less than* 20, just use `{0,19}`.

Comment: Please always use the minimum threshold value inside limiting quantifiers, it is best practice and will help avoid issues if a regex is used with a regex library that is not able to parse such quantifiers with missing min value.

Answer (score 1):

Use PyPi regex:

```py
,(?![^()]*\))|(?<=\((?=[^()]{20})[^()]*),
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Vk0vyE/1).

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##nZIxT8MwEIX3/IqjDLHRKSSpgA5pK2BgqlhgagtKU6exIHZku1IQ8NvDpSkSNOoAw0n2Z7@z7j1Xb67Qatg0sqy0cWDERtSeE7WDMZjBnXAg1VrUoHNwhbSQ6bJMEVZbB0xp10HsMA@gFWhXCNMRC6/yRSBoA6gNQoQRxIBx8FPM4ebxAdjm2Fsyh1IbQSxVEIeQFalJMyeMhZSwVFau21MBFe0VLaywfODRLM@iroywVmrVzuMjm57Mnxhfni04/2DTZLxgbDreofc4/OTdIUffq4xUju38COx2xX53Q/CT2/vZ7Hqy2CThJDnvNj5C6x3n3ikc8W4vw2/J36zsqcnZQ6ZN71Z0SNoYDtlfUum98L@QPGotM2EpnDnZ7FLjGIechqpJ0v3GIG8vUadeBDurl/uk9p1a5@fxEOEqpLqgGiGMIqpL@n7DaNk0Xw):

```py
import regex
text = r"Get index of this comma, but (not this , comma). Get other commas like, or ,or, 1,1 2 ,2. (not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma, if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)"
reg_expression = r',(?![^()]*\))|(?<=\((?=[^()]{20})[^()]*),'
print(regex.sub(reg_expression, '<COMMA>\g<0></COMMA>', text))
# Get index of this comma<COMMA>,</COMMA> but (not this , comma). Get other commas like<COMMA>,</COMMA> or <COMMA>,</COMMA>or<COMMA>,</COMMA> 1<COMMA>,</COMMA>1 2 <COMMA>,</COMMA>2. (not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma<COMMA>,</COMMA> if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)
indices = [x.start() for x in regex.finditer(reg_expression, text)]
print(indices)
# [23, 70, 75, 78, 81, 86, 131]
```

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^()]{20}                any character except: '(', ')' (20
                               times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for-loop with some if statements. This is not an ideal code, but gets you the answer.  Here is an example:

```
textString = 'Get index of this comma, but (not this , comma). Get other commas like , or ,or, 1,1 2 ,2.(not this ,) BUT (get index of this comma, if more than 20 characters are inside the parentheses)'
parFlag = False #flag to check ()
commas = []
lastPar = 0 #last seen ()
for i in range(len(textString)):
    if(textString[i]=='('):
        parFlag = True
        lastPar = i
    if(textString[i]==')' or i-lastPar>=20):
        parFlag = False
    if( textString[i] == ',' and not parFlag):
        commas.append(i)
```